# xml send from android app to a ip:port

Tags: android, xml, androidhttpclient

I created an android app and it will send an xml data to a particular ip:port.the code is working good without any error or warning.

but how we can identify that the sending xml will reached the ip:port correctly.if any way to identify that tha data is reached the port correctly.

my code given bellow.

```
 //xml sending


DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:9900/");     
// Make sure the server knows what kind of a response we will accept
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
// Also be sure to tell the server what kind of content we are sending
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

try
{
//xmlString is my xml data
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlString, "UTF-8");
entity.setContentType("application/xml");
httppost.setEntity(entity);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             // execute is a blocking call, it's best to call this code in a thread separate from the ui's
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("message",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("message",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
                }
            }).start(); 



      BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
       String strResponse = null;
       if (response != null) {
           try {
               strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
           } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
               Log.e("message",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e("message",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
           }
       }
       Log.e("WCFTEST", "WCFTEST ********** Response" + strResponse);    


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
   // ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("message",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
    Toast.makeText(OrderlistActivity.this, ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(OrderlistActivity.this, "Xml posted succesfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
  }
```

only "no Response" message in the logcat.but how we can identify that the data is reached at the port

Comment: your HHTP Client is sending xml data to a HTTP server (10.0.2.2) on port 9900.. so if you have access to the server.. ensure the ip is correct and it is listening on port 9900 (instead of the default 80) and write some code to read the incoming data and dump it to a file with a timestamp.

Comment: @Rohit:sir,that means the android section is correct.then please give me a small outline of service(in server) which is used to catch the data in the server

Comment: do you have access to the server 10.0.2.2 ? if yes, which web-server is running on it? Apache/IIS etc. ?

Comment: @Rohit:The Server is Accessable and the web service is IIS